# Some __builtin_sin does not work

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, built-in

I defined function

```
double builtin_test(double y)
{

  double x = __builtin_sin(y);

  return x;
}
```

thought it should work, but when coompiling

C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\USTAWI~1\Temp\ccNuVeYz.o:test6.c:(.text+0x5): undefined ref
erence to `sin'

how to make it work?

Comment: Why are you calling `__builtin_sin` anyway? It's not portable.

Comment: -lm ? could you elaborate (i previously never used this built-ins, got no clear view)

Comment: It is entirely possible that `__builtin_sin()` actually refers to `sin` in the C math library, which means, on Unix-like platforms, you need `g++ test6.c -lm` to include the math library. [This will happen when there is no trivial implementation of `sin` available on that architecture, in other words, the "standard library one is as good as it gets here"]

Comment: this makes no change, I do not understand this built-ins but shouldnt they work without any library?

Comment: PS i off-ed the msvcrt by -nostdlib, because the effect i want to get is no reference to msvcrt.dll and just intrinsic sin

Comment: How does the standard `sin` function not meet your requirements?

Comment: I still think the problem is that `__builtin_sin` is implemented as `sin`, because there is no immediately simple way to implement `sin`. Which means that you either need to implement your own `sin` function, or use the runtime library one. You may want to investigate linking to the C runtime as a static library.

Comment: @mats could you hint quick the switch to link it staticaly? (im about new in mingw things)

Comment: @kt it is not a question of requirments - i need to know how builtins work

Comment: Use `-static`, but it's approx 4 years since I last worked with gcc on Windows.

Comment: Not however that `-static` will not change how `__builtin_sin` is implemented, just whether the linker links to a DLL or to a LIB file.

Comment: not sure how it is but it is possible that in mingv there is no option to link with static libc 9not sure)

Comment: does it all just mean that sin cannot be built-in? maybe i should try some other to se improvement over library version

Comment: @user2214913: "@ kt" (without the space) does not notify me. Use "@ Keith" or "@ KeithThompson". Tab completion may also work, depending on how you're accessing the site.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to see as an "improvement"?

Comment: the whole advantages of built-ins (check some page - to long to answer ya)

Comment: If you call sin, the compiler recognizes it and handles it the same as __builtin_sin. That doesn't mean it inlines an implementation (though it might with long double on x87 with -ffast-math), it will normally call the standard library libc. But it knows some things, so it can compute sin(constant) at compile-time, it knows that sin does not write in random places in memory, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not REALLY an answer (but then, the question isn't exactly clear either) - it just got too long for a comment, and I don't want to chain 2-3 comments...

It is important to understand that the MAIN reason for `__builtin_*` functions is to support things that the compiler knows how to do - and sometimes, that turns into simply calling the relevant standard library function, rather than actually doing anything special.

If we take `sin` as an example, in x87, there is a `fsin` instruction that can be generated. But if the compiler just sees a bunch of math, it won't know that the code does `sin`, so won't produce the `fsin` instruction, just do a bunch of multiply, subtract, add, etc to perform that calculation. So using `__builtin_sin` inside the standard library or header, for example like this:

```
double sin(double x)
{
   return __builtin_sin(x);
}
```

will generate a `fsin` instruction.

I ran some experiments with gcc and clang on my machine, and I was not able to convince the compiler to actually calculate sin at runtime and NOT call the `sin` function. The clang version of the code decided to calculate my entire loops worth of `sin` values into a constant - which is of course a good win over doing 100 calculations, but not exactly what we're looking for.

Note that the `fsin` instruction is quite slow, and to perform individual calculation steps using simple instructions is quite possibly equally fast - but we don't want to inline that every time `sin` is used (and certainly don't want the compiler to "know" how to do that).

Comment: well ok, I think built-ins are for optymisation, if such __built_in_sin is resolved as normal call is there any optimisation over normall call? If i use my own _sin ina ssembly will marking the calls as built-ins (tied to my _sin probably in linking step) optymise this my own version too

Comment: The main point of builtin functions is not to make things faster because the code is better, but to generate better code because the compiler understands the builtin funciton in a different way than it would do for a general call to a function it doesn't even have the source for. But in this case, it turns out the compiler doesn't have a better way than "call the C library math function". Try doing the same with `__builtin_bswap`, and it may be different.

Comment: that is what i also think now, but this is anyway vague - Is there no way to force mingw/gcc to use for example inlined fsin (fsin in place not any function call) I know fsin is slow but it would at least correspond well with some nice meaning of built-in

Comment: right now it just seems so that built_in is more like hint only, like inline may be real built_in or no

Comment: There MAY be, but is that REALLY what you want. I bet it's slower to use `fsin` than `sin`.

Comment: There is inline asm to force the compiler to emit the instruction you want.